# Friendly URL or url-rewriting

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I am working on a site that uses such a url

```
 www.domain.com/hotels/hotel-name
```

I would like visitors just to see

```
 www.domain.com/hotel-name
```

This can probably be done in the .htaccess file with a rewrite condition but I don't know how.

Thank you for helping

Comment: Have you tried searching for some basic introductions to mod_rewrite? This site isn't really here to give people the exact code for every case so that they don't need to learn for themselves.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [RedirectMatch](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html)  directive :

Put the following Redirect above other rules in your htaccess file

```
 RedirectMatch 301 ^/hotels/([^/]+)/?$ /$1
```

This example would redirect all files from the **/hotels/** folder, if you want to redirect a particular file from that folder , you can use the following:

```
 RedirectMatch 301 ^/hotels/(file_name)/?$ /$1
```

Now if a visiter enters www.example.com/hotels/hotel-name then will be externally redirected to www.example.com/hotel-name